# Load new page when clicking Submit button in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app with a form which takes a file name and a value, passes it to a python function which uses them for some processing and then stores an image file in the 'static folder'.

Upon clicking the 'Submit' button in the form, I want the image to be displayed in a new webpage. How do I go about doing this?

```
@app.route('/burndown', methods=['GET','POST'])
def output_burndown_chart():
    if request.method == "POST":
        sprint_num = request.form['sprint_number']
        file_name = request.form['file_name']
        dir_name = "./files"
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
        burndown_gen(file_path,sprint_num)             #Does some processing and store a file in 'static'
    return render_template('burndown_form.html')
```

burndown_form.html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('output_burndown_chart') }}" method="post">
    <label for="file_name">File Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="file_name"><br>
    <label for="sprint_number">Sprint Number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="sprint_number"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Route to display the chart

```
@app.route('/burndown/chart', methods=['GET','POST'])
def output_chart():
    return render_template('test.html')
```

test.html

```
<body>
<h1>BurnDown chart</h1>
</body>
<img src="../static/plot.png">
</body>
```

Note: Have omitted parts of code for brevity

Comment: check your test.html body part first. May be it causes problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution if your folder structure looks like this

```
app.py
static
   ->plot.png
   ->test.png

templates
   ->index.html
   ->test.html
```

```
<body>
  <h1>BurnDown chart</h1>
  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='plot.png')}}">
</body>
```